# parent child class StackOverflowError exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parent-child

I have Two Class in school package

**Class school**

```
package school;

public class people 
{
    String Name = null; 

    public String getName() 
    {
        return "Super Class Name : " + Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**Class Students**

```
package school;

public class students extends people 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         people objpeople1   = new people();
         people objpeople2   = new students();

         objpeople1.setName("David");
         objpeople2.setName("Davis");

         System.out.println(objpeople1.getName());           
         System.out.println(objpeople2.getName());  
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() 
    {   
     return  "Child Class Name is: "+ getName();
    }
}
```

The first getName method is working fine.When I tried to use the second one its generating exception.

objpeople2.getName() is generating java.lang.StackOverflowError exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public String getName(){
    return "Child Class Name is: " + super.getName();
}
```

Your `objpeople2.getName()` is accessing the `getName()` of the current class, which causes calling the same method recursively that's way StackOverFlorError Exception was thrown. Use `super` keyword to refer to the super class of the current class.

Answer (score 1):

In you child class, you are calling `getName()` method recursively, which causes out of memory, hence StackOverflowException.

Try to call like bellow.

```
@Override
public String getName(){
    return "Child Class Name is: " + name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply I figured it out Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public String getName() 
{   
 return  "Child Class Name is: "+ getName();
}
```

In this method getName() calling as recursive call. Hence it never ends the calling of same method its giving `StackOverflowException`

Answer (score 0):

Changed it as Below.Its working Now

```
@Override
public String getName() 
{   
 return  "Child Class Name is: "+ super.Name;
}
```